# Create LOG files when creating multiple DATA files for tempdb?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've a question that I can't seem to find an answer to (and I can't test it out for a few weeks so I'm doing research now during my downtime).

Should I be creating corresponding LOG files for every DATA file I create?

eg. if I create tempdev3.mdf, should I also create templog3.ldf?

Or do the LOG files get created automatically as and when needed by the SQL Server?

I'm using MS SQL 2008 R2 EE but I think the answer equally applies to 2005 and 2012.

Comment: FWIW I voted to migrate to [dba.se] not to close as "opinion based". The answer to this is entirely factual. i.e. there is no general benefit of multiple log files at all.

Comment: I had no idea there was a dba.stackexchange.com portal. I've always asked sql questions in stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple log files, but there is no point, SQL Server will only write to them one at a time sequentially, so there is no performance gain here at all.

All you do with having multiple log files is create more files to manage and potentially more downtime after a crash as there is possibly more log file than strictly necessary to initialise.

Have a quick look at the following article for a bit more info:

[Multiple log files and why they’re bad](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/multiple-log-files-and-why-theyre-bad/)

Bottom line, don't bother with it.

Comment: Thanks steoleary. I've managed to read a couple of online books regarding this. They all (basically) say 'use only 1 log file per db'.